# Data migration tool magento2?

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

Using data-migration-tool i managed to migrate my m1 data into m2.
I referred below link.
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/migrate-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/

I downloaded the migration tool inside the m2 directory and it worked well.
Where my M1 files also on same server. Both DB also in same server.

My Questions are Does it work if :

1. I download migration-tool-kit to some new directory instead of downloading it into M2 directory?
2. Are both M1 and M2 files should be in same server? Does it work if both files are in different servers?
3. Both M1 and M2 Database should be in same server? Does it work if connection string of M1 and M2 are different?

Comment: 1) No, required to download in Magento2 directory. 2) Yes, Working on the different server.

Comment: Are both files to be same server?

Comment: If your Magento1 and Magento2 is placed in two different server. Then also you can migrate data from M1 to M2.

Comment: Get my point or not?

Comment: 2nd point is fine i got it. Can we download migration-tool into custom folder? instead of m2 directory? Does it work? have you tried?

Comment: Not working. Because in the migration process it deals with Magento 2. So in the custom folder, you can not migrate data.

Answer (score 1):

1. The data-migration-tool should be in your vendor directory and you should bring it using composer. This is documented here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html. The data-migration-tool i a Magento module. Magento runs it. You can't put it anywhere else.
2. Magento 1 and Magento 2 instances don't have to be on the same server, but they can. This does not really impact anything.
3. M1 and M2 databases don't have to be on the same MySql server but they can be, This can improve performance drastically. This can be achieve with the following configuration. Excerpt from **project-root/vendor/bmirsd/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce/1.12.0.2/config.xml**. If M1 and M2 DBs are on different servers you need to make sure that the M2 server has access to M1 Mysql Server.

   ```
   <direct_document_copy>1</direct_document_copy>
   ```

More on configuring and using the data-migration-tool provided by Magento refer to the oficial docs. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-configure.html

Comment: hi @vito, i started migration getting below error after that,

  Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\htdocs\magentonew\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\Step\Eav\Data.php on line 292

Comment: @jafarpinjar The undefined offset is a weird error to have. Are you sure there aren't any modifications made to the migration tool? For core issues regarding the migration tool I recommend raising an issue here https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool

Comment: No, I haven't made any changes to the core files